# Linux limiting upload bandwidth

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

I have a linux server that is reporting (on a 250 / 25 Mbps connection line) 240 / 3.5 Mbps. On the same network, another device (this one windows, and both wire-connected, no WiFi involved) is reporting 240 / 25 Mbps.

I have no idea even where can I start looking on. I am using Debian Buster, and the ethernet controller is a RTL8111/8168/8411. There are no options kernel parameters changed through sysctl.

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt this is a Linux issue, the rtl8111/8168 kernel module is mature and stable and should handle 850+ Mbps bi-directionally in most PC's without an issue. Not sure how you are testing that, but I would suggest testing with iPerf to verify throughput, first within the LAN between the server and the Windows machine, and then to a source outside the LAN.

Comment: @acejavelin I know, I know, but is a problem I am experiencing. Both machines are connected to same router by wire, in windows I go to speedtest.net, and in linux I use speedtest-cli, both using the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: speedtest-cli was reporting wrong upload bandwidths for some time. When doing the test with the current master, it just works as expected (also confirmed with iperf3).